# R groupby and calculate special average

Tags: r, dataframe

Sample dataframe:

```
id <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b")
id2 <- c(1,2,3,4,1,1,2)
value <- c(200,150,250,100,120,60,50)
df = data.frame(id,id2,value)
df

id id2 value adj_val
a  1   200
a  2   150
a  3   250
a  4   100
b  1   120
b  1   60
b  2   50
```

I want to group by `id` and find sum of values with `id2` higher than `id2` of that row divided by sum of all values of that group. So for the above example:

```
id id2 value adj_val
a  1   200   0.71    # (150+250+100)/(200+150+250+100)
a  2   150   0.5     # (250+100)/(200+150+250+100)
a  3   250   0.14    # (100)/(200+150+250+100)
a  4   100   0       # (0)/(200+150+250+100)
b  1   120   0.22    # (50)/(120+60+50)
b  1   60    0.22    # (50)/(120+60+50) 
b  2   50    0       # (0)/(120+60+50)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(adj_val = map_dbl(.x = seq_along(id2),
                          ~ sum(value[id2 > id2[.x]])/sum(value)))

  id      id2 value adj_val
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 a         1   200   0.714
2 a         2   150   0.5  
3 a         3   250   0.143
4 a         4   100   0    
5 b         1   120   0.217
6 b         1    60   0.217
7 b         2    50   0
```

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr` and `purrr`

```r
library(tidyverse)
id <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b")
id2 <- c(1,2,3,4,1,1,2)
value <- c(200,150,250,100,120,60,50)
df = data.frame(id,id2,value)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(adj_val = map_dbl(id2, ~ sum((.x < id2) * value) / sum(value))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   id      id2 value adj_val
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 a         1   200   0.714
#> 2 a         2   150   0.5  
#> 3 a         3   250   0.143
#> 4 a         4   100   0    
#> 5 b         1   120   0.217
#> 6 b         1    60   0.217
#> 7 b         2    50   0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>